# Wrong coloring in ggplot line graphs

Tags: ggplot2

I have created a `ggplot` graph with three lines. Each line represents a different column in a data frame and colored in a different color. For some reason, the colors in the final graph are not coordinated to the code.

The data frame:

```
Scenario 1 Scenario 2 Scenario 3 Years
0.0260     0.0340     0.0366     1
0.0424     0.0562     0.0696     2
0.0638     0.0878     0.1150     3
0.0848     0.1280     0.1578     4
0.1096     0.1680     0.2074     5
0.1336     0.2106     0.2568     6
```

This is the code:

```
ggplot(ext2, aes(x = Years))+
geom_line(aes(y = `Scenario 1`, color = "darkblue"))+
geom_line(aes(y = `Scenario 2`, color = "darkred"))+
geom_line(aes(y = `Scenario 3`, color = "darkgreen"))+
xlab("Years")+
ylab("Quasi - extinction probability")+
ggtitle("2 mature individuals")+
geom_segment(aes(x = 45,y = 0.5, xend = 45, yend = 1.1),linetype = "longdash")+
geom_segment(aes(x = 75,y = 0.2, xend = 75, yend = 0.5),linetype = "longdash")+
geom_segment(aes(x = 0,y = 0.5, xend = 100, yend = 0.5),linetype = "longdash")+
geom_segment(aes(x = 0,y = 0.2, xend = 100, yend = 0.2),linetype = "longdash")+ 
geom_text(x = 20, y = 0.80, label = "CE")+
geom_text(x = 40, y = 0.35, label = "EN")+
scale_colour_manual(values = c("darkblue", "darkred","darkgreen"), labels = c("Scenario 1","Scenario 2","Scenario 3"))+
theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
theme_minimal()
```

and this is the graph:

[Click here to see graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1hma.png)

The problem is that what I defined as 'scenario 3' in the code is actually a representation of 'scenario 2' in the data frame. You can see it according to the values under scenario 2 in the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

For `ggplot`, the data needs to be in long format before you plot. Then, you can make "Scenarios" (i.e., `name`) the group, so that you can manually color the individual lines (i.e., with `scale_colour_manual`).

```
library(tidyverse)

ext_long <- ext2 %>%
  pivot_longer(!Years)

ggplot(ext_long, aes(x = Years, color = name)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = value)) +
    xlab("Years") +
    ylab("Quasi - extinction probability") +
    ggtitle("2 mature individuals") +
    geom_segment(aes(
      x = 45,
      y = 0.5,
      xend = 45,
      yend = 1.1
    ), linetype = "longdash") +
    geom_segment(aes(
      x = 75,
      y = 0.2,
      xend = 75,
      yend = 0.5
    ), linetype = "longdash") +
    geom_segment(aes(
      x = 0,
      y = 0.5,
      xend = 100,
      yend = 0.5
    ), linetype = "longdash") +
    geom_segment(aes(
      x = 0,
      y = 0.2,
      xend = 100,
      yend = 0.2
    ), linetype = "longdash") +
    geom_text(x = 20, y = 0.80, label = "CE") +
    geom_text(x = 40, y = 0.35, label = "EN") +
    scale_colour_manual(
      values = c("darkblue", "darkred", "darkgreen"),
      labels = c("Scenario 1", "Scenario 2", "Scenario 3")
    ) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    theme_minimal()
```

**Output** (only have a small part of the data, which is the reason the lines do not extend across the graph)

[image]

Data

```
ext2 <- structure(
    list(
      Scenario.1 = c(0.026, 0.0424, 0.0638, 0.0848,
                     0.1096, 0.1336),
      Scenario.2 = c(0.034, 0.0562, 0.0878, 0.128,
                     0.168, 0.2106),
      Scenario.3 = c(0.0366, 0.0696, 0.115, 0.1578,
                     0.2074, 0.2568),
      Years = 1:6
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-6L)
  )
```